# Is an upgrade mapping file necessary when upgrading custom components from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, sql-server-2012

I'm upgrading some SSIS custom components from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2012.

According to MSDN:

> **Mapping the Versions of Your Custom Object for Upgrade**:
>   SQL Server 2008 Integration Services adds a new subfolder, UpgradeMappings, in the %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS folder. This subfolder is where you deploy the mapping files that tell the package upgrade engine how to map SQL Server 2005 Integration Services objects to their new SQL Server 2008 equivalents.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645943(SQL.100).aspx

I could not find this information for SQL Server 2012. I got the impression that this was not necessary for 2008 -> 2012.

**Is an upgrade mapping file necessary when upgrading custom components from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2012?**

Comment: So did you find a solution to this?